# How can I use custom fonts on a website?

Tags: html, fonts

In order for my website to look good I need to use a custom font, specifically, Thonburi-Bold. The problem is - the font does not get displayed unless the user has installed it. It also isn't displayed in firefox.

Is there a workaround to this problem?

Comment: There are several old questions around the topic. Some of them are dated, but time is spent more productively in improving the answers than giving short answers to duplicates. (Any really short answer to the question tends to be wrong or essentially incomplete.)

Answer (score 109):

You have to import the font in your stylesheet like this:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: "Thonburi-Bold";
    src: url('Thonburi-Bold.ttf'),
    url('Thonburi-Bold.eot'); /* IE */
}
```

Comment: +1 for the IE comment

Comment: it seems to work with `src: url('Thonburi-Bold.otf')`, too

Answer (score 13):

You can use CSS3 `font-face` or webfonts

**@font-face usage**

```
@font-face {
   font-family: Delicious; 
   src: url('Delicious-Roman.otf');
}
```

**webfonts**

take a look at Google Webfonts, http://www.google.com/webfonts

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there is a way. Its called custom fonts in CSS.Your CSS needs to be modified, and you need to upload those fonts to your website.

The CSS required for this is:

```
@font-face {
     font-family: Thonburi-Bold;
     src: url('pathway/Thonburi-Bold.otf'); 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

CSS lets you use custom fonts, downloadable fonts on your website. You can download the font of your preference, let’s say `myfont.ttf`, and upload it to your remote server where your blog or website is hosted.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myfont;
    src: url('myfont.ttf');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you gotta put your font as either a .otf or .ttf somewhere on your server.

Then use CSS to declare the new font family like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: MyFont;
    src: url('pathway/myfont.otf'); 
    }
```

If you link your document to the CSS file that you declared your font family in, you can use that font just like any other font.