# Platform Font Face HTML

Tags: html, fonts, font-face

I know not every platform contains the same font faces. What would happen if a font face that is not known is used? Is it possible to be downloaded or would it choose a different font face?

Comment: You're looking for web fonts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use custom fonts on a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585186/how-can-i-use-custom-fonts-on-a-website)

Comment: Web fonts (“custom fonts”) might be a conclusion to be drawn, but not the answer to the questions aked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser will use a default font.  You can control your styling by coding backup fonts to use if your first pref isn't supported.

Below is an example of styling backup fonts in CSS.

P { font-family: Cambria, Georgia, Serif }

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a browser will default to a font that the computer has installed, usually Arial (windows) or Helvetica (mac). There are several solutions, my favorite resource for web fonts is [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts), absolutely free. If you *have* to have a particular font, [Typekit](https://typekit.com/) has the largest selection, but be prepared to pay!

With Google Web Fonts, literally just google: Google Web font similar to (The Font you want).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If the name of font not installed in the user’s system is mentioned in a `font-family` declaration (or in a `<font>` tag), then that name is simply ignored. No automatic download takes place. (Downloadable fonts, aka. web fonts, are a different story, but for them, you really specify font URLs and assign names to them.)

The font used is then determined by other factors. If other fonts are listed in the `font-family` list, they are tried. Failing that, the font of the parent element is used. Ultimately, if we then come to the top level, the document as a whole, without finding any font name known in the system, then the browser’s default font is used. This font is typically changeable by the user, though few people change it. Typically it is Times New Roman in Windows systems.