# How can I use symbol fonts like marvosym in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I would like to use some special fonts which are used in LaTeX. For example, I would like to display the `\Pluto` from `marvosym`:

[image]

**How can I display this symbol with HTML / JavaScript / CSS without using an image?**

The font can be downloaded from http://www.marvosym.com/download.html

It is symbol 201 in that font.

I tried

```
<p style="font-family: 'marvosym'">&#201;</p>
```

with Chrome, but it only showed É (I have installed this font; `fc-list | grep marvosym` shows it)

Comment: According to http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/, `marvosym` is not installed. Do I have to restart my system so that chrome "detects" that   mavosym is installed on my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link the font in a standard CSS way, as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13585273/1161631

I would actually recommend providing at least TTF/OTF and WOFF formats, since they seem to have a good coverage together, see [`@font-face` on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp).

Then you should be able to use `&#201;` to access the symbol stored in the slot. However, remember that this is an abuse of the unicode slots, will not copy-paste properly, and a fallback will show some non-sense in case the font doesn't load properly.

If you have a `marvosym.woff` the following example will work in many browsers:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'marvosym';
            src: 
            url('marvosym.woff') format('woff');
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p style="font-family: marvosym">&#201;</p>
</body>
</html>
```