# How do I use the font League Gothic on my website?

Tags: html, css, fonts

How do I use the font League Gothic on my website?

- [Link to the League Gothic GitHub repo](https://github.com/theleagueof/league-gothic)

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585186/how-can-i-use-custom-fonts-on-a-website

Answer (score 0):

If you have already downloaded the *League Gothic* font, use `CSS3's @-font-face Rule`. Define your font like this:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: League-Gothic;
    src: url(wherever your font is located);
}
```

Try to use **.ttf/.otf** fonts because they have the best of support among the 5 major browsers (IE, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari).