# How can i use gotham rounded font in my bootstrap template?

Tags: css

```
<label style="font-family: 'gotham rounded'">this is label</label>
```

i am not able to use the 'gotham rounded font for my bootstrap template'. I am using ubuntu for the development May be it is not installed on my pc. I will be hosting the template so it has to be compatible on windows as well as on ubuntu.

can anybody help??

Answer (score 2):

this is typically done by importing the font to your font-face

```
    @font-face{
    font-family: "Thonburi-Bold";
    src: url('Thonburi-Bold.ttf'),
    url('Thonburi-Bold.eot'); /* IE */
}
```

This is further explained here:[How can I use custom fonts on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585186/how-can-i-use-custom-fonts-on-a-website)
(possible duplicate?)

Answer (score 1):

Gotham Rounded is not installed on any Operating System. You have to buy the font-kit for this one.

http://www.typography.com/fonts/gotham-rounded/styles/

It is $179, so unless you work for a company and they're willing to buy this for the project, I would suggest using a similar free font.

[Similar fonts at identifont.com](http://www.identifont.com/list?3+Gotham%20Rounded+0.30+202D+1+1Z4S+2+L1C+2+2JVE+2+2I90+2+XD+2+L70+2+3EDP+2+O4H+2+66W+2+3HBN+4+2XZW+4+3A9A+4+3CIW+4+3IM7+4+3IM5+4+2GON+4+2GK5+4+F3X+4+6DC+4+KYR+4+37J4+4+43QF+4+8K8+4+3LY8+4+GLP+4+4H9+4+E2+4+3D5X+4+2Y03+4)